# How to merge two entity classes with same structure?

Tags: entity

Suppose I am looking for file formats associated with markup languages.

Lets say I would like to first find out about the ones which are web associated.

I look at the `EntityClassList["FileFormat"]` to find that they are in the class, `EntityClass["FileFormat","Web"]`.

So I use the following query to find the markup language formats.

```
FilteredEntityClass[
    EntityClass["FileFormat","Web"],
    EntityFunction[c,
        StringMatchQ[c["Extension"],"*ml",IgnoreCase->True]||StringMatchQ[c["Name"],"*markup*",IgnoreCase->True]
    ]
]//EntityList
```

But I now also want the ones which are data associated like `XML` so would like to look in the class `EntityClass["FileFormat","Data"]` as well.

My question is what function `f` below will help me resolve this query.

```
FilteredEntityClass[
    f[EntityClass["FileFormat","Web"],EntityClass["FileFormat","Data"]],
    EntityFunction[c,
        StringMatchQ[c["Extension"],"*ml",IgnoreCase->True]||StringMatchQ[c["Name"],"*markup*",IgnoreCase->True]
    ]
]//EntityList
```

Basically `f` needs to `Merge` two `EntityClass` which have the same structure, i.e. `Properties` since they are both from the same parent class `"FileFormat"` into a new merged class and then the filter will be applied.

Comment: Have you looked at `CombinedEntityClass`?

Comment: I don't how to use `CombinedEntityClass` but it looks like it is used to perform SQL joins like, inner, outer - left & right and cross. But what I am looking here is what SQL calls `UNION ALL` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This represents an entity class of type "FileFormat" whose entities are members of one class or the other:

```
EntityClass["FileFormat", "EntityClasses" -> "Web" | "Data"]
```

And you can use it like you would any other entity class:

```
EntityList[
    FilteredEntityClass[
        EntityClass["FileFormat",
            "EntityClasses" -> "Web" | "Data"
        ],
        EntityFunction[c,
            Or[StringMatchQ[c @ "Extension", "*ml", IgnoreCase -> True],
                StringMatchQ[c @ "Name", "*markup*", IgnoreCase -> True]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that simplest answer for your question is join the two `EntityLists` and then run all your calculations on that.  Since the `EntityProperties` are the same, it shouldn't cause any issues.

Consider the following:

```
function = 
     EntityFunction[c, 
      StringMatchQ[c["Extension"], "*ml", IgnoreCase -> True] || 
       StringMatchQ[c["Name"], "*markup*", IgnoreCase -> True]]; web = 
     FilteredEntityClass[EntityClass["FileFormat", "Web"], function] // 
      EntityList;

data = FilteredEntityClass[EntityClass["FileFormat", "Data"], 
        function] // EntityList;

combined = Join[web, data];

results = DeleteMissing[
     EntityValue[combined, "EntityPropertyAssociation"], Infinity]
```

[image: output]

If you look at the `InputForm` of the `EntityProperties`, you will see they are all the same.